# cleaning vs to be cleaned

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

Look at this example below

> The carpet needs___________ before we use it.
>
> a) cleaning  b) to be cleaned

Which one would be more appropriate in the given context and why?

My thought process was:  a person always clear a carpet so it should have a passive sense --> to be cleaned.
But the first one also looks fine. Additionally, please clarify if we are using cleaning as a gerund in the first option.

Answer (score 3):

Both are passive and both are idiomatic. The version with the gerund-participle is what Huddleston & Pullum (2002) call a concealed passive construction and the version with the infinitive an ordinary passive construction:

> With a small number of catenative verbs, notably *need*, *require*, *deserve* and *want*, a gerund-participial may be passive while lacking the usual marking of the passive — we refer to this as a **concealed passive construction**.
>
> i The house needs to be painted. [ordinary passive] 
>   ii. The house needs painting. [concealed passive]
>
> The catenative complement in [i] is overtly marked as a passive by the auxiliary *be* and the past participle form *painted* ... while [that] in [ii] lacks such marking although [it is] interpreted in the same way. (p. 1199-1200)

Note also that the version with the gerund-participle can freely take a by-phrase complement as in "the carpet needs cleaning by you".

Comment: Agreed. Both are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Both forms are fine. I would probably prefer 'to be cleaned' which is very common and idiomatic. To me, 'needs'+gerund sounds a bit more complicated, although still fine to use.